# Throw and exception and move on in pandas

Tags: pandas, object, exception, valueerror

I have created a pandas dataframe called `df` with the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

ds = {'col1' : ["1","2","3","A"], "col2": [45,6,7,87], "col3" : ["23","4","5","6"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ds)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(df)

  col1  col2 col3
0    1    45   23
1    2     6    4
2    3     7    5
3    A    87    6
```

Now, `col1` and `col3` are objects:

```
print(df.info())

 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   col1    4 non-null      object
 1   col2    4 non-null      int64 
 2   col3    4 non-null      object
```

I want to transform, where possible, the object columns into floats.

For example, I can convert `col3` into a float like this:

```
df['col3'] = df['col3'].astype(float)
```

But I cannot convert `col1` into a float:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A'
```

Is it possible to create a code that converts, where possible, the object columns into float and by-passes the cases in which it is not possible (so, without throwing an error which stops the process)? I guess it has to do with exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make a test whether the content in a string, object or not, in which cases the conversion won't be made. Did you try this ?

```py
for y in df.columns:
    if(df[y].dtype == object):
        continue
    else:
        # your treatement here
```

or, apparently in `pandas 0.20.2`, there is a function which makes the test : `is_string_dtype(df['col1'])`

This is in the case where all the values of a column are of the same type, if the values are mixed, iterate over `df.values`

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it.

```
def convert_float(x):
    try:
        return x.astype(float)
    except:
        return x


cols = df.columns

for i in range(len(cols)):
    
    df[cols[i]] = convert_float(df[cols[i]])


print(df)
print(df.info())
```